# How to structure Symfony projects inside /src directory?

Tags: symfony

I understand how and why to structure a Symfony project. I just wonder if is there any preferred structure under the `/src` direcotry. Beside the `Controller`, `DependencyInjection`, `Entity` etc. how do you organize your source code?
Just crowd everything under `Model`? Group larger logical bulks into dirs like `Service`, `Model`, `Job` etc? Some group their files by functionality like:
`Order`, `Product`, `PopupManager` etc. What is the most useful?

Comment: You should have your custom bundles under /src, like AppBundle , or DemoBundle etc ... Inside your Bundles, you will find your /Entity, /Controller folders ...

Comment: @Gauthier No, that's absolutely the "no way" for symfony projects. New best practices point you to a single bundle for your application. Symfony 4 even force you, somehow, to have a all your code under `src` without any bundle. Moreover this question is not a "good one" for SO standards as is primarily opinion based as there will never be a "right answer". This will bring us to the next level: in every way you decide to split your code, as long as it's under `src`, is a good way.

Comment: Hu ... ok ... I didn't know that ... Weird but why not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many answers to this question. I think it highly depends on what your application involves. The following are some suggestion but keep in mind that you need to imagine the structure of your application by yourself.

Little project (less than 6months and a not too much of maintenance):

```
.
├── Controller
├── Entity
├── Factory
├── Provider
├── Repository
├── Security
└── YourCustomThing
```

Or if you prefer a domain approach (I do) you can have more something like this:

```
.
├── Product
│   ├── DTO
│   └── Model
└── User
    ├── Model
    ├── Provider
    └── Security
```

If you have a more complex application, then you should probably learn about [DDD](https://github.com/dddinphp) or [CQRS](http://getprooph.org/). Here is a little DDD example inspired by the [DDD Cargo Sample](https://github.com/codeliner/php-ddd-cargo-sample) (but there is a lot more to tell about DDD apps, as well as CQRS ones).

```
.
├── Application
│   ├── Booking
│   │   └── Dto
│   └── Exception
├── Http
│   └── Action
├── Infrastructure
│   ├── Persistence
│   └── Product
│       ├── ActionFactory
│       └── BookingFactory
└── Model
    └── Shop
```

Hope it helps.